# How do I create a read only MySQL user for backup purposes with mysqldump?

Tags: backup, mysql, database-backup, read-only

I'm using the `automysqlbackup` script to dump my mysql databases, but I want to have a read-only user to do this with so that I'm not storing my root database password in a plaintext file.

I've created a user like so:

```
grant select, lock tables on *.* to 'username'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
```

When I run `mysqldump` (either through `automysqlbackup` or directly) I get the following warning:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema' when using LOCK TABLES
```

Am I doing it wrong? Do I need additional grants for my readonly user? Or can only `root` lock the `information_schema` table? What's going on?

**Edit:**

GAH and now it works. I may not have run FLUSH PRIVILEGES previously.

As an aside, how often does this occur automatically?

**Edit:**

No, it doesn't work. Running `mysqldump -u username -p --all-databases > dump.sql` manually doesn't generate an error, but doesn't dump information_schema. `automysqlbackup` does raise an error.

Comment: Oops... from the man page for `mysqldump`:

    mysqldump does not dump the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database. If you name that database explicitly on the command line, mysqldump silently ignores it

Seems like either the man page is out of date (and it does raise a warning), or `automysqlbackup` is performing some additional checks on the dump for `information_schema`.

Not sure which it is, but it's not related to user grants.

Comment: It's not a GRANT issue. You don't need to backup INFORMATION_SCHEMA (See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

Comment: To add to what SmallClanger said, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a virtual database, rebuilt each time MySQL is restarted, so there's no point in backing it up because you can't restore it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops... from the man page for `mysqldump`:

```
mysqldump does not dump the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database. If you name that database explicitly on the command line, mysqldump silently ignores it
```

Seems like either the man page is out of date (and it does raise a warning), or `automysqlbackup` is performing some additional checks on the dump for `information_schema`.

Not sure which it is, but it's not related to user grants.

**Edit**

Yep, it's a bug in `automysqlbackup` version 2.5.1 (using MySQL 5.1.41 under Ubuntu 10.04) - it tries to backup `information_schema` when it shouldn't.

FIX: Add `information_schema` to to `DBEXCLUDE` on line 76 of the script.

Comment: It's not a GRANT issue. You don't need to backup INFORMATION_SCHEMA (See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html)

Comment: To add to what SmallClanger said, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a virtual database, rebuilt each time MySQL is restarted, so there's no point in backing it up because you can't restore it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Those permissions should be all that's needed for the mysqldump.

Since you've granted LOCK TABLES, and it's erroring on LOCK TABLES, seems like the permissions are inconsistent.  Have you run a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`?

Answer (score 1):

Create user

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dump'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'plaintext-pass';
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `my-db`.* TO 'dump'@'localhost';
```

Check privileges

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR dump@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for dump@localhost                                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dump'@'localhost'                                                      |
| GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW, EVENT, TRIGGER ON `my-db`.* TO 'dump'@'localhost' |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Use yor favorite editor to create file `~/.my.cnf` with `chmod 400`

```
[client]
user=dump
password=plaintext-pass
```

Create folder for dumps, just as example

```
mkdir ~/db-dumps
```

Check if it works

```
mysqldump -u dump --hex-blob --routines --triggers my-db | gzip > ~/db-dumps/manual-my-db-dump-`date +%F`.sql.gz
```

Optionally you can make dumps `daily` and `weekly` then remove all `daily` older then month

```
#m h  dom mon dow   command
0  3  *   *   0,2-6 /usr/bin/mysqldump -u dump --hex-blob --routines --triggers my-db | gzip > ~/db-dumps/daily-my-db-dump-`date +%F`.sql.gz;
0  3  *   *   1     /usr/bin/mysqldump -u dump --hex-blob --routines --triggers my-db | gzip > ~/db-dumps/weekly-my-db-dump-`date +%F`.sql.gz;
0  4  *   *   *     /usr/bin/find ~/db-dumps/ -name "daily-*" -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \;
```